# How do I display the contents of local Storage after button click without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want the contents of the local Storage to be displayed when the submit button is clicked without having to refresh the page. I don't see the changes made until I manually refresh the page

This function handles the page load. When a button is clicked it shows wrong data. The correct data is only shown when the page is manually refreshed.

```
const loadData = () =>
  document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('load', displayStorage());
```

This is the event listener that handles saving:

```
notesForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const save = (sid, spost, sdate) => {
    const obj = { id: sid, post: spost, date: sdate };
    localStorage.setItem(`${sid}`, JSON.stringify(obj));
  };
  save(generateId(), post.value, dateFormat());
  loadData();
});
```

Comment: In your form submit, just call `displayStorage()` instead of `loadData()` ? Your `loadData` function just hooks to the page load event, so it will execute once the page has loaded and only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `loadData` function is only adding an event listener. It is not displaying the data in localStorage.

Try replacing the `loadData()` call in the submit callback with `displayStorage()`.

Answer (score 0):

try providing the function as a handler to be invoked by the load event. Not invoke it by yourself

```
const loadData = () =>
  document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('load', displayStorage);
```

You can try reloading the page by yourself using `location.reload`

```
notesForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const save = (sid, spost, sdate) => {
    const obj = { id: sid, post: spost, date: sdate };
    localStorage.setItem(`${sid}`, JSON.stringify(obj));
  };
  save(generateId(), post.value, dateFormat());
  loadData();
  location.reload()
});
```